# RRavenDB: EsentTempPathInUseException: Temp path already used by another database instance

Tags: ravendb

We have RavenDB running on IIS without any issues for a few years. A recent windows update breaks it. The database cannot start up. The error message is: 
**Microsoft.Isam.Esent.Interop.EsentTempPathInUseException: Temp path already used by another database instance**.
We end up build another server and transfer all data to the new server.
Anybody has the same issue? How to fix it?

Comment: The RavenDB version we are using is 2.5.2879 on Windows Server 2012 R2 standard 64 bits. IIS version is 8.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out Windows update block the access to the database file. We're running RavenDB on IIS. It is easy to fix. Move the database file out of IIS folder to another folder and set the settings in the web.config:

```
<add key="Raven/DataDir" value="D:\Projects\RavenDBFiles\YourRavenDbServer\Database\System"/>
<add key="Raven/CompiledIndexCacheDirectory" value="D:\Projects\RavenDBFiles\YourRavenDbServer\CompiledIndexCache" />
<add key="Raven/AssembliesDirectory" value="D:\Projects\RavenDBFiles\YourRavenDbServer\Assemblies" />
```

Comment: Notice the web.config that comes in the `/Web` folder of the downloaded zip file now has an extra key `<add key="Raven/WorkingDir" value="APPDRIVE:\Raven\" />` which allows you to keep using the tilde (i.e. `~\Database\System`) **Remember to give your AppPool permission to write to `APPDRIVE:\Raven\`**

Answer (score 0):

This exception has multiple possible (and different) reasons and should be investigated for underlying reason. 
You can try upgrading to latest stable (2.5.2952) from [here](http://ravendb.net/downloads/builds) and if that doesn't help, continue this on [RavenDB group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ravendb).

Comment: Tried 2.5.2952, the same error: Exception type: EsentTempPathInUseException 
    Exception message: Temp path already used by another database instance
   at Raven.Storage.Esent.TransactionalStorage.Initialize(IUuidGenerator uuidGenerator, OrderedPartCollection`1 documentCodecs) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable-2.5\Raven.Database\Storage\Esent\TransactionalStorage.cs:line 431

Comment: I have the same issue and I didn't find how to fix it. We have runing RavenDB on our development server for a year and it stopped working. I'm using 2.5.2935 version. Anybody knows how to fix it?

Comment: Some time ago Microsoft didIIS patch that might cause this. As a first step move RavenDB folders outside of IIS (Raven/DataDir, Raven/Assemblies, Raven/CompiledIndexCacheDirectory)

Comment: And imho those kinds of questions are much more visible in Raven's Google Group => faster responses